# Unable to deploy functions in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay in my nuxt app.
For that, I installed **razorpay dependency** using **npm i razorpay**

My index.js files starts with

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const Razorpay = require('razorpay')

const admin = require('firebase-admin')

const crypto = require('crypto')
```

But after writing the function(basic helloWorld function) and deploying it gave me an error unable to deploy function.
But when I commented below line the helloWorld function deployed successfully.

```
//const Razorpay = require('razorpay')
```

Again I uncommented above line and it still gives me error unable to deploy.

Version info

Node **v12.18.3**

Firebase **v8.16.2**

**My Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.2",
    "cookieparser": "^0.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.6",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.3",
    "razorpay": "^2.0.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vuexfire": "^3.2.5"
  },
```

Comment: Could you please share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you will need to put the following in the Firebase Cloud Function to integrate the Razorpray:

```
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
var key_id = "YOUR_RAZORPAY_KEY_ID";
var key_secret = "YOUR_RAZORPAY_KEY_SECRET";

var instance = new Razorpay({
  key_id: key_id,
  key_secret: key_secret
});
```

You need to follow the next steps to integrate it:

- Signup for razorpay and grab your Key_Id and Key_Secret from [Razorpray](https://razorpay.com)
- Integrate the checkout modal from razorpay in the front end to accept the payment details from user.
- Implement Order API in the backend.
- Capture Authorized payments.

Please have a look into the following [Medium tutorial](https://medium.com/@abdulrauf76143/payment-integration-in-few-steps-with-angular-firebase-razorpay-e7e674eb5057) for better understanding and this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Crazyprogrammer1/razorpay-payments/blob/master/functions/index.js) for a code example.

********** UPDATE **********

Regarding Cors error, please make sure the following:

1. Import Cors

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

2. Call the cors module at the top of each function as following:

```
exports.createPayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        // your function body here - use the provided req and res from cors
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you imported cors as following? const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

Comment: Yes as imported const cors = require('cors')({origin: true}); . Can you please help me how to add cors to my code. Here is my code.

Comment: Could you please share the error it is giving you regarding the Cors?

Comment: payment:1 Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/createPayment' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Updated code below. Same error again. -------                                                       
                 Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/createPayment' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: There is one more error.    -----------------   POST https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/createPayment net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: The firebase log gave me this.     ---------   createPayment
ReferenceError: Razorpay is not defined

Comment: I thought you created a Razorpray instance as mentioned in the top of my answer. But now again checking your code, I can see you didn't created any instance providing the Razorpray Key ID and Key Secret. Please follow the steps provided above to integrate the Razorpray

Comment: Actually, this post is available publically, so for security purpose, I removed them and added text. But the actual key is present in my code. I got that key from Razorpay. Instead of declaring a variable first for keys, I entered them directly, as a string. Also, I even tried your method to create Razorpay instance but the problem remains the same.

Comment: I solved the deployment error. 
I changed my directory to functions. And again did npm i razorpay. By doing this the razorpay dependency appeared in package.json folder in functions. And I was able to deploy function to firebase. Also, I have installed the cors and used it in my code. But after everything is correct in my code it still gave me cors error.

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const Razorpay = require('razorpay')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
admin.initializeApp()


//Function to Create Payment
exports.createPayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('payments')
      .add(req.body.data)
      .then((payment) => {
        var instance = new Razorpay({
          key_id: 'rzp_test_my_key',
          key_secret: 'my_secret_key',
        })

        var options = {
          amount: req.body.data.amount * 100,
          currency: 'INR',
          receipt: payment.id,
          payment_capture: 1,
        }
        instance.orders.create(options, function (err, order) {
          res.status(201).send({ data: order })
        })
      })
  })
})

// Function to Verify Payment

exports.verifyPayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const order = req.body.data

    const text = order.razorpay_order_id + '|' + order.razorpay_payment_id
    var signature = crypto
      .createHmac('sha256', secret_key)
      .update(text)
      .digest('hex')

    if (signature === order.razorpay_signature) {
      res.status(201).send({ data: { message: 'Successfull Payment' } })
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({ data: { message: 'Signature mismatch' } })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: CORS error is finally solved by changing functions.https.onRequest to functions.https.onCall.